# Base rplot font argument

Tags: r, plot

I was looking to have a bold ylab in a base r plot.
the simplest way is the argument `font.lab=2` which was not working for boxplot

```
plot(1:10,xlab="hello",font.lab=2,cex.lab=0.7 ) # works fine
boxplot(1:10,xlab="hello1",font.lab=2,cex.lab=0.7 ) # not working
boxplot(1:10,xlab=expression(bold("hello2")),cex.lab=0.7 )  # a workaround but cumbersome
```

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]

Usually the Graphical Parameters are the same for all base r plot.

Does anyone knows why the `font.lab=2` was dropped in base r boxplot ?

Comment: Is this question really about why it was dropped? or are you asking how to create a bold axis label for `boxplot`?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick , i was surprised that ``font.lab`` was not working for ``boxplot`` . the third line of code is fine. i don't know if there is a way force the ``font.lab`` or other graph argument doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `font.lab` argument for `boxplot`, you should add it to your `par` like this:

```r
par(font.lab = 2)
boxplot(1:10,xlab="hello1", cex.lab=0.7)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice workaround ! less cumbersome for me as i set margins before the plot